# Google calendar "Guest can modify" true is not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

I want to update the  Google calendar event from my application in sync. Guest "can modify" event is turned on in Google.But while updating guest in my application in sync it is not reflecting to all guests of that event and event owner too.
Except this one every thing is working fine.

pl any help.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I Guess need to press Save or Ctrl+S after editing calendar it will work